# Indexes in the pg_indexes table but does not existed in the \d result

Tags: postgresql, psql

I am using Postgres 12 in Docker in development.

In my project the primary key using UUID, and when I logged into the pgsql console, and try to setup indices for better performance.

When executing a `select` on `pg_indexes` table, it shows all indexes related to our tables.

```sql
SELECT
    tablename,
    indexname,
    indexdef
FROM
    pg_indexes
WHERE
    schemaname = 'public'
ORDER BY
    tablename,
    indexname;
```

But when I used `\d tablename` to show the table info, it only show the table structure, no other information.

Answer (score 1):

try to `off` the `tuple only mode` by `\t`

then run `\d tablename`